# Evaluating $\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { x{ \left( 1-x \right) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 4 } } }{ { \left( 2-x \right) }^{ 2 } } dx } $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

While solving a problem I was stuck at this integral:

> $$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { x{ \left( 1-x \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  } }{ { \left( 2-x \right)  }^{ 2 } } dx } $$

Does this have a closed form? I tried to convert it into an integral that could be evaluated using beta function. But I couldn't. Please help me evaluate this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we set $z=1-x$, then $z=u^4$,
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(1-x)^{1/4}}{(2-x)^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^{1/4}(1-z)}{(1+z)^2}\,dz = 4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^4(1-u^4)}{(1+u^4)^2}\,du$$
and the last integral can be computed through partial fraction decomposition, leading to:
$$ I = \color{red}{\frac{1}{4} \left[-20+3\pi \sqrt{2}+6\sqrt{2} \log\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right]}. $$

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Could you elaborate the step of partial fractions? I was stuck over there itself.

Comment: @AdityaKumar: $$(1+u^4)=(u^2+u\sqrt{2}+1)(u^2-u\sqrt{2}+1)$$

Comment: Ohk. I missed that. Thanks.